# Memoir: make the spacing between lines one-and-a-half and make an empty line between two paragraphs including no indent (like in Word)

Tags: memoir, paragraphs, line-spacing

I tried following for one-and-a-half-spacing:

```
\OnehalfSpacing
\setSingleSpace{\baselinestretch}
```

And this for making paragraphs look like in word (empty line between, no indent):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside, oldfontcommands, parskip=full]{memoir}
```

Nothing worked. Please help.

Comment: Hello, while your description is clear, a _complete_ minimal working example would help both you and us to understand the problem better. You can use some kind of a faux-text, such as lorem ipsum or `blindtext.sty` to "hide" your actual text part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @OlegLobachev an MWE from you would have been very helpful. Here is a simple one that does paragraphing as you asked for.

```
% parprob.tex  SE 650510

\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\OnehalfSpacing
\setSingleSpace{\baselinestretch}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}  %% no paragraph indent
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip} %% blank line between paragraphs

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

EDITED to correct second call to `\lipsum` as pointed out by @barbarabeeton.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you. I have corrected my code.